# Web API 2 does not set Thread.CurrentPrincipal in certain scenarios

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

While trying to debug why custom authentication filter does not work in our in-memory integration tests, I found that there is a difference in the way different subclasses of HttpRequestContext set Principal.

Most of them ( `OwinHttpRequestContext`, `SelfHostHttpRequestContext`, `WebHostHttpRequestContext`) set Thread.Principal like this

WebHostHttpRequestContext.cs:

```
public override IPrincipal Principal
        {
            get
            {
                return _contextBase.User;
            }
            set
            {
                _contextBase.User = value;
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = value;
            }
        }
```

But some do not set it at all (`BatchHttpRequestContext` and `RequestBackedHttpRequestContext`).

Is this a design decision and I need to rewrite parts of application to not use Thread.Principal) or is it a bug that needs to be/will be fixed?